# Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением 1

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    float a, x, b, c, F;
    printf("Введіть a: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &a);
    printf("Введіть x: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &x);
    if (c < 0 && a != 0) {
        printf("Введіть с: ");
        scanf_s("%f", &c);
        printf("Введіть b: ");
        scanf_s("%f", &b);
        F = ((-a)*x*x*x - b) / c;
    }
    else { if (c > 0 && a = 0) {
        printf("Введіть с: ");
        scanf_s("%f", &c);
        F = (x - a * a*a) / (-c); }
    else {printf("Введіть b: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &b);
    F = a * x + 5 * b;
    }
    }
}
```

Пишет что ошибка с "с" в 23-й строчке (Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением 1)

Answer (score 2):

Вы, наверное, хотели написать не

```
if (c > 0 && a = 0)
```

а

```
if (c > 0 && a == 0)
```

? И, кстати, вы используете неинициализированную переменную `c`: какой смысл проверять, меньше она нуля или нет, если вы вводите ее только **после** проверки?...

Comment: спасибо огромное) Сейчас все исправлю, говорили же не путать = и ==. Эх..))

Comment: Ну, если вопрос решен - закрывайте, принимая ответ (птичка слева).